# making levels in swift storyboard

Tags: swift

I want to make an app where I create different levels by changing the speed. But I'm getting "Expected parameter type following ':'" error and I don't know how can I do this with using enum.

```
enum Difficulty {
    case easy(timeInterval: 1)
    case medium(timeInterval: 0.6)
    case hard(timeInterval: 0.3)

}
    
@IBAction func easyButton(_ sender: Any) {
  
}
@IBAction func mediumButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func hardButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
  
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Why do you put `(timeInterval: 1)` after the enum cases?

Comment: I'm trying to make the "catch Kenny" game. I want 3 levels (easy, medium,hard) so I put timeInterval for every level.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hardcode associated values for enum cases.
Instead, declare a property that would return a desired value for each case:

```swift
enum Difficulty {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard

    var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
        switch self {
        case .easy:
            return 1
        case .medium:
            return 0.6
        case .hard:
            return 0.3
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let difficulty: Difficulty = .easy
let timeInterval = difficulty.timeInterval
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compiled because of wrong syntax. To solve your task you can inherit you `enum` from `Double` and use `rawValue` to get a difficulty value (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149).

```swift
enum Difficulty: Double {
    case easy = 1
    case medium = 0.6
    case hard = 0.3
}

let timeInterval = Difficulty.medium.rawValue
print(timeInterval) // Prints "0.6"
```